# Is there possible to run docker-android on arm64

Tags: android, docker, arm64

I have an ARM64 board which runs Linux. 
The system is built by Yocto, I can make it support Docker.
But how to build an android docker image?
When I search on Docker hub, there 11 OS supported on aarch64(such as Debian Ubuntu and so on) but no Android.
Does anyone know How to build an android docker image run on arm64?